Error executing DDL in Hibernate after upgrading Spring Boot (v2.1.6 to v3.1.4) and Java (8 to 21) on AWS EKS
Problem Description
I upgraded my Spring Boot application from v2.1.6 to v3.1.4 and Java from 8 to 21. While the application runs fine locally (using Docker and Minikube), I encounter a database schema migration error in the AWS EKS staging environment. The error is related to Hibernate executing a DDL statement.
Error Log
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table test_data modify column data tinyblob not null" via JDBC [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1]

Key Changes


Spring Boot upgraded from 2.1.6 to 3.1.4.
Java upgraded from 8 to 21.
Locally, the application connects to MySQL via JDBC using Docker and Minikube.
Deployed to AWS EKS using a MySQL database.


Environment Details
•  Local Setup: Docker, Minikube with MySQL 8.0.
•  AWS EKS Staging: AWS EKS with MySQL engine 8.0.35 (AWS RDS).
•  Database Schema Management: Hibernate  auto-DDL is set to none.
•  Java Version: openJDK 21 on Eks, Oracle jdk 21 on local
•  Spring Boot Version: 3.1.4
•  Hibernate Version: 6.2.9
Configuration Snippets

Dockerfile which gets deployed on staging environment

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 openjdk:21-jdk-slim
ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JAVA_OPTS=""
WORKDIR /app
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
COPY target/my-app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Duser.timezone=UTC", "-jar","app.jar"]


application-staging.properties (relevant parts)

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testuser?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver



Entity Definition (simplified)

Entity
@Table(name="test_data")
public class TestData {

    public TestData(){}

    public TestData(String type,
                        byte[] data,
                        String metadata) {
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
        this.metadata = metadata;
        this.receivedAt = Instant.now();
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    private String type;

    @NotNull @Lob
    private byte[] data;
    ...

}



The SHOW query on RDS table

SHOW CREATE TABLE test_data;

===Output of above query below====
CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `received_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `receivedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY <...>
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=174604166 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_as_ci


application properties file


spring.config.activate.on-profile  = staging
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.application.name = testApp
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://<masked>

aws.redshift.url=jdbc:redshift://<masked>/
aws.redshift.clusterId=<masked>
aws.redshift.dbUser=<masked>
aws.redshift.dbPassword=${REDSHIFT_PASSWORD}

spring.datasource.username = <masked>
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration

spring.data.rest.base-path = repositories

# We use multiple thymeleaf configs and none of them are spring MVC
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration

#Email Notifications
email.password = <masked>


jwt.expiryLength.default = <masked>
jwt.expiryLength.rememberMe = <masked>
jwt.secretKey = <masked>

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true


## Rabbit Configuration
amqp.enabled = true
spring.rabbitmq.host = <masked>
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username = <masked>
spring.rabbitmq.password = ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}

spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=4
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.max-concurrency=8
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=20000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier=2.0
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-interval=60000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=5

test.agent.docker.registry = <masked>


## Write collected data to connected relational database as blobs
datawriter.jpa.enabled = true
datawriter.s3.enabled = true

# AWS configuration for the various services, like S3, Athena, & Glue
aws.region = <masked>
aws.accessKey = <masked>
aws.secretKey = <masked>
aws.kms.arn = <masked>
sns.topic.arn.staging = <masked>
sns.topic.arn.production = <masked>


athena.enabled = true
athena.outputlocation = <masked>
athena.service.options.clobber = true

# Configure S3 locations for data, athena results, etc.
s3.data.bucket = <masked>
s3.data.environment = <masked>
s3.athena.bucket = <masked>

# Configure workflows for AWS glue
workflows.glue.enabled = true
workflows.glue.serviceRole = <masked>
workflows.glue.s3Path = <masked>

redshift.tmp-dir = <masked>
redshift.database = <masked>

# TODO -- this shouldn't be in config. Pass it in as env vars or through a secret instead
google.api.client_id = <masked>
google.api.client_secret = <masked>

# eksctl stuff
eksctl.enabled=true
eksctl.cluster.name=testCluster
eksctl.cluster.region=<masked>
eksctl.nodegroups.metal.name=metal-nodes
eksctl.nodegroups.metal.availZone=<masked>
eksctl.nodegroups.metal.capacity=1


# Configure rotating proxy
rotating-proxy.hostname=<masked>
rotating-proxy.port=<masked>
rotating-proxy.shared-dc.username=<masked>
rotating-proxy.shared-isp.username=<masked>
rotating-proxy.password=<masked>

engagement-services.twitter.enabled = false

springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled = false

## In-Memory Credentials
security.inmemory.user.name = <masked>
security.inmemory.user.password = <masked>
security.inmemory.user.roles = ADMIN,USER
security.cors.allowedOrigins = http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:4200

# Turning off the default health checks for data sources
management.health.db.enabled=false
# Custom health checks
athena.health.check.enabled=true
athena.health.check.threshold=20
mysql.health.check.enabled=true

# application.properties
logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.password=${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true


SpringDataConfig class

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
   basePackages = {"com.org.test.repository"}
)
public class SpringDataConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer{

    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Bean
    public SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory projectionFactory() {
        return new SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(springDataDataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[]{"com.org.test.domain"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
            = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",
            "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl");
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
            "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean("springDataDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource springDataDataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JdbcTemplate springDataJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(springDataDataSource());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        Class[] allEntities = entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager()
            .getMetamodel().getEntities().stream()
            .map(entityType -> ((EntityType<?>) entityType).getJavaType())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new Class[0]);
        config.exposeIdsFor(allEntities);

        // By default set the repository rest exposure to off
        // Only reporitories specified with @RepositoryRestResource will have a REST api exposed
        config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
}

Questions

Why does this issue occur only in AWS EKS and not locally?
Is there a compatibility issue between Hibernate 6.x and MySQL TINYBLOB in the upgraded setup? Also, the RDS table already had data for the given schema which is correct. No where in code do I execute the DDL statement then why spring implicitly is executing the DDL?
How should I resolve this error? Should I modify the column type or adjust Hibernate settings? I can not re-create schema or lose data in this process what options do I have?


Never let hibernate manage your schema, use something like Flyway or Liquibase to do that. That way you are in control instead of hibernate. Only use this feature for testing purposes but never for your real production schema.

Hi @M.Deinum: I am using Flyway to manage my schema but not sure why this DDL query is being generated. Is there a property to turn this off completely apart from the ones I am already using and shared above?

Probably the column properties for data column in hibernate do not match with the database column properties and therefore hibernate wants to change the data type of the database column. Take a look at those column properties.

There are several to prevent hibernate managing the schema none of them are used at the moment (at least not from the snippet in your question). But you want to add spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none and spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false. If that doesn't work you probably have some others in there that override these then please add your full application.properties to the question. If this still happens on AWS you might want to check the environment for one of these variables.

Hi @M.Deinum,
I did try with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false & spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none. But I still get the same error. The value has been added to my application-staging.properties file and applicaton starts 2024-12-09T10:38:50.307Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.test.testApplication           : The following 1 profile is active: "staging" 

That isn't an error that is just an info message.

@M.Deinum the error message is exactly the same I have shared above. 2024-12-09T10:39:16.396Z  WARN 1 --- [main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table campaign_data modify column data tinyblob not null" via JDBC [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1] org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table campaign_data modify column data tinyblob not null" via JDBC [Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1  ... 

Well then you have still something in your environment overriding those values. But without your full application.properties and profile specific ones that will be impossible to answer.

@M.Deinum I have added properties file for reference.

That is the generic one is there a profile one as well? If this doesn't kick in, you either aren't using the auto configuration for JPA or another property is overriding this (you don't have an accidental hibernate.properties/xml or persistence.xml somewhere?).

@M.Deinum the above shared is profile specific one.But for testing and to resolve this issue I have kept it to application-staging.properties file and copied all properties from application.properties file so that there are no discrepancy.
In my resource folder I do not have hibernate.properties/xml or persistence.xml

Well if it isn't there the only conclusion is (or 2 actually) is that either you aren't using auto-configuration and decided to configure the entitymanager yourself and/or you have some dangling environment variables that override these.

@M.Deinum for reference I have added SpringDataConfig class where entity manager is configured has it something to do with entityManagerFactory() method where additional properties are set?

That class renders the spring.jpa properties in your application.properties useless. You will need to disable the DDL generation into your own configured one. Why did you add it in the first place? Additional properties can be configured through spring.jpa.properties.<name of property>. You don't need to add the DataSource/JdbcTemplate just remove them and inject the DataSource into the EntityManagerFactory method.

Thanks for pointing it out @M.Deinum. To give you more context the application performs CURD operations on AWS RDS. Not sure why this update was in there(legacy).
I have removed the DataSource/JdbcTemplate beans from the class and also remove **properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update"); , properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect")); . Also injected Datasource directly to entityManagerFactory ** public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource). Is this what you mean by above comment?

Well  you don't really need this class at all. If you want to add those additional properties just add them as spring.jpa.properties.<name of property> and then you can remove the datasource, jdbctemplate and entitymanagerfactory methods as well as the @ EnableJpaRepositories annotation (assuming your @SpringBootApplication class is in the com.org.test. If you don't want to make that big of a change now remove the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property as that is set to update (or set it to none).

Understood, this resolves the issue. It was the property in the EntityManagerFactory that was causing the error.

@M.Deinum can you also help me find the correct naming strategy with current springboot version and hibernate dependency:
properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",           "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl");        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");
